# Am I misreading "On Cayley's Enumeration of Alkanes (or 4-Valent Trees)"?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, polya-counting-theory

E. M. Rains and N. J. A. Sloane, [**On Cayley's Enumeration of Alkanes (or 4-Valent Trees)**](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/cayley.html),
Journal of Integer Sequences, Vol. 2 (1999) is only available in HTML, which makes it harder to read than a nice LaTeXified PDF but easy to quote the section which is confusing me:

> Fix *k*, and let
> *T<sub>h,n</sub>*
> be the number of (*k*-1)-ary rooted trees with *n* nodes and height at most *h*.  (The height of a node in a rooted tree is the number of edges joining the node to the root.)  By convention the empty tree has height -1.
>
> Let *T<sub>h</sub>*(*z*) = 
> SUM
> <sub>*n* >= 0</sub>
> *T<sub>h,n</sub> z<sup>n</sup>*.
> Then *T*<sub>-1</sub> (*z* )  = 1,
> *T*<sub>0</sub> (*z*)  = 1+ *z*,
> and for *h*>1,
>
> *T*<sub>*h*+1</sub> (*z*)  =  1+ *z* 
> **S**<sub>*k*-1</sub>
> (*T<sub>h</sub>* (*z* )),        (4)
>
> where
> **S**<sub>*m*</sub>
> (*f*(*z*)) denotes the result of substituting *f*(*z*) into the cycle index for the symmetric group of order *m*!.  For example,
>
> **S**<sub>3</sub>
> (*f*(*z*))  =  ( *f*(*z*)<sup>3</sup> +3 *f*(*z*) *f*(*z*<sup>2</sup>) + 2 *f*(*z*<sup>3</sup>)) / 3!.
>
> Equation (4) holds because if we remove the root and adjacent edges 
> from a rooted tree of height
> *h*+1 we are left with an unordered (*k*-1)-tuple of trees of height *h*.
>
> Let C<sub>2*h,n*</sub> be the number of centered *k*-valent trees with *n* nodes and diameter 2*h*,
> and let C<sub>2*h*</sub>(*z*)
>  =  
> SUM <sub>*n* >= 0</sub>
> C<sub>2*h,n*</sub> *z*<sup>n</sup>.  By deleting the center node
> and adjacent edges,
> we see that any such tree corresponds to an unordered *k*-tuple of (*k*-1)-ary rooted trees of height at most *h*-1, at least two of which have height exactly *h*-1.  Therefore
>
> C<sub>2*h*</sub>  =  ( 1+ *z* 
> **S**<sub>*k*</sub>
> (*T*<sub>*h*-1</sub> (*z*))) - (1+ *z*
> **S**<sub>*k*</sub>
> (*T*<sub>*h*-2</sub> (*z*))) - (*T*<sub>*h*-1</sub> (*z*)-*T*<sub>*h*-2</sub> (*z*))(*T*<sub>*h*-1</sub> (*z*) - 1 ).        (5)
>
> The three expressions in (5) account for the *k*-tuples of rooted
> trees of height at most *h*-1, *k*-tuples of rooted
> trees of height at most *h*-2, and rooted
> trees with exactly one subtree at the root with height *h*-1, respectively.
>
> Finally, let *C*<sub>*n*</sub> denote the number of centered *k*-valent trees with *n* nodes, and *C*(*z*) =  
> SUM <sub>*n* >= 0</sub>
> *C<sub>n</sub>z<sup>n</sup>*.
> Then
>
> *C*(*z*)  =  
> SUM <sub>*h* >= 0</sub>
> *C<sub>2h</sub>*(*z*) .
>
> For *k* = 4 we obtain
>
> *C*(*z*)  =  z + z<sup>3</sup> + z<sup>4</sup> + 2 *z*<sup>5</sup> + 2 *z*<sup>6</sup> +
> 6 z<sup>7</sup> + 9 z<sup>8</sup> + 20 z<sup>9</sup> + 37 z<sup>10</sup> + 86 z<sup>11</sup> +
> 181 z<sup>12</sup> + 422 z<sup>13</sup> + ... ,
>
> which is the corrected version of Cayley's sequence (1),
> [A000022](http://oeis.org/A000022).

However, it seems to me that in the sum $C_(z) = \sum_{h \ge 0} C_{2h}(z)$  the first two terms of $C_{2h}$ telescope, and likewise half of the third term, to give

$$C(z) = - (1+ z S_k (T_{-2} (z))) - T_{-2} (z) + \sum_{h \ge 0} (T_{h-2} (z)-T_{h-1} (z))T_{h-1} (z)$$

I presume, although it's not explicitly stated, that $T_{-2}(z) = 0$, so that simplifies to

$$C(z) = - 1 + \sum_{h \ge 0} (T_{h-2} (z)-T_{h-1} (z))T_{h-1} (z)$$

Now, the coefficients of $T_h$ are $T_{h,n}$ which must be non-negative, and since $T_{h,n}$ is defined as "*the number of ($k$-1)-ary rooted trees with $n$ nodes and height **at most** $h$*" (my emphasis) it is clear that $T_{h-1,n} \ge T_{h-2,n}$. Therefore the sum in the simplified expression for $C(z)$ is convolving a polynomial whose coefficients are all non-positive with a polynomial whose coefficients are all non-negative, and the result must be a polynomial whose coefficients are all non-positive.

But all of the coefficients of $C(z)$ should be non-negative, and Rains and Sloane explicitly give its initial coefficients as non-negative numbers.

Have I misunderstood something? Is there a sign error in the paper? Or is it a more serious flaw?

For what it's worth, I suspect that the third term of $C_{2h}$, which accounts for rooted trees with exactly one subtree at the root of height $h-1$, is missing an application of $S_k$, and should be $(T_{h-1} (z)-T_{h-2} (z))S_k(T_{h-1} (z) - 1)$, but I admit that I'm slightly out of my depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked through some small terms with a CAS.

Firstly, I made an error in telescoping the first two terms, so that $-1$ shouldn't be there: this is clear when considering a finite telescope, as $$\sum_{h=0}^{n} (1 + z S_k(T_{h-1}(z))) - (1 + z S_k(T_{h-2}(z))) = z S_k(T_{n-1}(z)) - z S_k(T_{-2}(z))$$

Secondly, the telescoping doesn't carry over trivially from finite to infinite terms. That is, $$\sum_{h=0}^n C_{2h}(z) = z S_k(T_{n-1}(z)) + T_{n-1}(z) - \sum_{h=0}^n (T_{h-1}(z) - T_{h-2}(z)) T_{h-1}(z)$$

but the terms which telescoping has pulled out of the sum have larger (absolute, non-negative) coefficients than the (non-positive) coefficients of the convolution.